# Convert Premiere Pro 2022 to 2020

Tags: premiere, premiere-pro

I was trying to convert Premiere Pro 2022 project to 2020 for my colleagues to use. The converter site has a message popped out when I clicked CONVERT. The error message is "Invalid file type. [Error 3]". I have a screenshot attached. How can I convert to a lower version from Premiere 2022. Thank you!

Truly appreciate.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I think Adobe only officially maintains compatibility within single version numbers of Premiere.  See here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/sea/premiere-pro/using/backward-compatibility.html

You might be able to export the project as another format, like you would when exporting to another editor (like [this example exporting to Davinci Resolve](https://www.mediaequipt.com/export-from-premiere-to-davinci-resolve/)).  But you're likely to lose some edit information (plugins etc), and it will be difficult to do.  You're better off all working on the same version.

Answer (score 0):

**Usually method with unpacking PRPROJ with 7-zip helps me.**

1. Unpack project file with 7-zip
2. Open in notepad.
3. Edit version in line number 4.
   `Version="40"` is for Premiere 2022.
   `Version="39"` is for Premiere 2021.
   `Version="38"` is for Premiere 2020.

You can even edit it to `Version="30"`, then Premiere should propose you to resave it to actual version.
[image]

4. Save the file and rename in to prproj.
   4.1. Or pack it with 7-zip with these settings:
   [image]

Then rename to *.prproj

**Video explanation**